# Vimeo player enableTextTrack after loadVideo

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

I'm trying to force the credit to be one after changing the video with loadVideo function. 
Not sure I'm doing things the proper way, or if this is a bug in the API. 
Any one manage to make it work ?

```
var options01 = {
  id: 76979871,
  autoplay:true
};

var vimeoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('player_1', options01);
vimeoPlayer.enableTextTrack('fr').then(function(track) {
    // track.language = the iso code for the language
    // track.kind = 'captions' or 'subtitles'
    // track.label = the human-readable label
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.name);
});

$( ".changevideo" ).on( "click", function() {
  var id = $(this).data('vimeoid');
  vimeoPlayer.loadVideo(id).then(function(id) {
    vimeoPlayer.enableTextTrack('fr').then(function(track) {
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.name);
    });
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/romainmalauzat/pen/xyvyVW?editors=0010

Comment: It says the second video does not exist after I click on “video 2”, not sure what exactly that is supposed to have to do with the subtitle functionality …?

Comment: Sorry @misorude, my client removed the video 2 link. Now it's working again. But anyway the problem is the same with video 1, it should have the TextTrack on, like it is on the first video.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have finally used destroy, and rebuild the player each time. it's a hack, and shouldn't be the way, but that's all I have for now.

If any one as a better solution, I'm all ears. Thanks.